# Can I validate a preprocessor macro to make sure it's a number?

Tags: c++, validation, macros, c-preprocessor

I'm using macros to define simple variables inside my code (something like this):

```
#define foobar 1
//...
barfoo(foobar);
```

To prevent errors, I want to make sure `foobar` is a number by validating the input. `foobar` should always be a number, so it can be pretty simple.

Apparently, the preprocessor doesn't handle math, so any hope of generating some type error with arithmetic is lost.

I guess constants are really better for this reason, but I'm trying to use all macros so it is consistent in a configuration file I have (some do *need* macros). Regular expressions might have been an okay workaround, but GCC doesn't seem to support [with macros] this (plus, *http://xkcd.com/1171/*).

Comment: GCC supports regex since 4.9. Anyway, I imagine you'd have to do `#define ISNUM(x) ISNUM_##x()` and then tons of `#define ISNUM_0() 1` etc. You'd get an error if you don't have a macro defined for the input.

Comment: @chris not in macros

Comment: @chris What does that have to do with this question? The regex support that GCC has is for run-time regular expression matching, no preprocessor extension.

Comment: *I guess constants are really better for this reason* - Can you elaborate on your context/configuration situation, so that people can understand how to perhaps advise you about how to adapt or incorporate the solution you seem to know is the right one?

Comment: @hvd, True, I didn't realize it was regex for the PP at first because the question didn't have the note and it seemed odd to mention that lack of support in the first place given that it's well-known GCC was behind there.

Comment: @HostileFork I just said that because GCC will throw an error if the value is incorrect. However, there is a possibility of GCC failing silently (i.e. if there is a trailing semicolon that produces a bug but not an error).

Comment: A regex to validate an integer isn't problematic.  Using regex to work with irregular inputs is the problem.  `/-?[0-9]+/` or you can get a little fancier to reject leading zeroes, which I consider inadvisable (the rejection, not the zeroes).

Comment: What about `#define foobar (1)`, or `#define foobar (1+2)`? Is that supposed to be considered valid, invalid, or do you not care what happens for those definitions?

Comment: @hvd I never thought about that, but no, there should be no cascading of macros. Therefore, it should only be `define foobar 123` (or similar).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++11, there are type traits and static asserts that should serve your purpose:

```
#include <type_traits>

#define foo 1
// #define foo "bar" // will lead to a compiler error containing the message "foo is not int"

static_assert(std::is_integral<decltype(foo)>::value, "foo is not int");
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the comment on the question says that expressions should be disallowed as well, an answer that involves a compile-time check that an expression has integral type won't do the trick: that would detect no difference between `1`, `(1)`, and `(0+1)`, since all three are prvalues of type `int` with the exact same value.

Therefore, an answer would have to involve looking at the macro definition itself, and that's possible by stringising it, and putting the validation in a `constexpr` function that takes a string, and using that in a static assertion. Example for positive decimal unsuffixed integer literals:

```
#define A 1
#define B 2
#define C 3
#define D (4)

#define STR_(x) #x
#define STR(x) STR_(x)

constexpr bool is_number(const char *str) {
  return (*str >= '0' && *str <= '9') && (str[1] == '\0' || is_number(str+1));
}

#define VERIFY(x) static_assert(is_number(STR(x)), STR(x) " is not a number!")

VERIFY(A); // passes
VERIFY(B); // passes
VERIFY(C); // passes
VERIFY(D); // fails: (4) is not a number!
```

It would need to be extended if you need to handle suffixed literals as well (`123L`), or non-decimal literals (`0x123`). If as a special exception you'd want to allow the application of unary `-` to an integer literal, that too would need an extension.

This is almost certainly not worth protecting against. If someone decides that the code is more readable and/or maintainable if `D` is defined as `(4)`, or `(3+1)`, or `(C+1)`, instead of `4`, and if aside from this one assertion those definitions would work perfectly well, the assertion is something that would be ripped out of the code rather quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you only use macros where necessary and use constants otherwise.  Consistency isn't always the most important priority.

Comment: @Wintermute definitely answers the question here, but it's almost a question that shouldn't be answered. +1 to this answer as I would say this is a self-inflicted problem. If the OP were using constants instead of macros, then they would already be the correct type.

Comment: @void.pointer I have submitted an edit to Wintermute's answer bearing this caveat.

Answer (score 0):

There are good reasons to use constants instead of defines for this purpose.

Scott Meyers has a chapter dedicated to this in his book "Effective C++" : 
http://books.google.com/books?id=U7lTySXdFk0C&pg=PT41&lpg=PT41#v=onepage&q&f=false

Item 2: "Prefer consts, enums and inlines to #defines".

Using a constant can make debugging a lot easier, because the compiler has access to the name (rather than just the preprocessor substitution).

Defines also don't have the same type safety features (which is the issue you're presumably trying to work around here). They don't have the same scoping features.